# Android Studio Design Tab Grayed Out

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I imported a libgdx project into Android Studio to create the UI for my app. I tried to open the designer to easily add items to the UI, however the design tab from **View > Tool Windows > Designer** is grayed out. I assume it's because it's an imported project, would be great if anyone knew of a way to open the designer, thanks!

Comment: Do you really want a native android UI on top of your libgdx game?

Comment: I was more intending to use some layouts so I could hold UI portions of my game separate from where the actual game would be. For example a panel holding character information on the side.

Do you think it would be viable to build custom UI in the render method of libgdx and avoid any native UI?

Comment: I'd recommend using the libgdx UI system (namely scene2d.ui) for this. Games usually don't try to have a native look and feel and you will be able to keep testing your game on your desktop, without the need to deploy it on your phone every time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me! I didn't realize that libgdx had their own  UI.

Answer (score 1):

Scene2D comes with LibGdx which is usually used to create everything related to UI. I wouldn't recommend to use default Android UI with LibGdx game.

Here is some documentation an tutorials how to use Scene2D in your LibGdx project:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

It's also recommended to use Ninepatch for your UI elements such as buttons so it can scale the buttons and other elements correctly. There is also a documentation and tutorial for that here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches